# Archiving old data on SQL Server Express 2008

Tags: sql-server, archiving

[SQL Server 2008 Express]
[C# 4.0]

I've developed a winforms application, I want to give the user the opportunity to archive old data at the beginning of each year.

The user can for example connect to  to consult his archive.

The real scenario happens as follows: The user is working on the  database, till the beginning of the next year(2011), he clicks on , I want to copy then delete all 2010 transactional data (keeping customers, suppliers, employees, balances...) data to a new database called , I keep track of all archive filenames and location in an XML file.

I'd like to know the steps to follow on both sides, SQL and C# in order to achieve this task.

I welcome any suggestion, tip, samples, links, books...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Do you have a maintenance window to accomplish this task. This is to understand there is no transaction happening while archival process is in progress
- If you have a maintenance window below is my suggestion
- Step 1 - Get FUll DB backup during maintenance window
- Step 2 - Have a Archival Script which would delete the data for previous years
- Step 3 - Validate the Delete data, This can be tested and validated on a Test Data Set
- Step 4 - Delete the Data in batches. Sometimes you may end up with log full issues, You would be delete records in huge records sets, Make it batched delete
- Step 5 - In case of any issues, Use the Full backup taken in Step 1 and continue until you have a proper archival script